# alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView method not working in Appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, appdelegate, uialertviewdelegate

I had set UIAlertView in AppDelegate.m file.

But when I choose the button on the alert view.

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

was not working.

I had set UIAlertViewDelegate in the AppDelegate.h file.

and my AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:        (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
        {

         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:)
                                                 name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                               object:nil];

            NSString *remoteHostName = REACHABILITY_HOST;
            _hostReachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:remoteHostName];
            [_hostReachability startNotifier];

            return YES;
        }

        - (void) reachabilityChanged:(NSNotification *)note
        {
         if( [Reachability isExistNetwork] == NotReachable)
            {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil         message:@"my message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"         otherButtonTitles:@"set",nil];
                [alertView show];

            }

        }

        -(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
        {

            switch (buttonIndex) {

                case 0:
                    NSLog(@"ok!");
                    break;

                    // set
                case 1:

                    NSLog(@"set!");
                    NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];
                    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
                    break;

            }
        }
```

But the

```
-(void) alertView:(UIAlertView *) alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

was not enter this method.

Have anyone know what happened? thanks.

Comment: Your appDelegate class must conforms to the <UIAlertViewDelegate>      for example : @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate>.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code doesn't correctly set the delegate of the alert view.

You need to change the following line so that the delegate is the appropriate object (eg, `self`):

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil         message:@"my message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"         otherButtonTitles:@"set",nil];
```

Comment: Hi sapi, I had try to set delegate: nil or self, but the method still not working. Do you know what happened? thank you.

Comment: @dickfala - Where do you have the delegate method `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`?  If it's in the `AppDelegate`, and you set the delegate to `self` in the constructor, the methods should be called.  You may want to try `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:`

Comment: I had try to success, I set delegate to self, and "clean" my project. It's ok! Thank you ,sapi~ ^^

Answer (score 2):

You have to replace the line

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"my message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:@"set",nil];
[alertView show];
```

By this lines

```
UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"my message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:@"set",nil];
[alertView show];
```

You have to set delegate as self to call the delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

Check your delegate reference in the .h file. Put on the `UIAlertViewDelegate`.

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```